# The language is not supported on the server

Tags: language, spsite

I installed Language Packs for SharePoint Server 2010 from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3411

On creating a new site collection using PowerShell with "Language" option set to 1034 or any other language code, I get the following error:

*New-SPSite : The language is not supported on the server.*
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on support.microsoft, hope it helps. 
P.S: I did not test it.

1.) Open Registry Editor

2.) Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0

3.) Create a new Key under 12.0 called ServerLanguage

4.) Right-click ServerLanguage, select new String value and give it a name of 1033

Note: 1033 is valid for US English.  To determine the appropriate language value for other languages, see the following web site:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824907.aspx

5.) Close the Registry Editor

6.) Re-run the "SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard"

[The language is not supported on the server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2002277)
[The language is not supported on the server. 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/08/06/the-language-is-not-supported-on-the-server.aspx)