# SP 2016 Configuration Failed - Failed to create the configuration DB

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, configuration, language

I installed SharePoint 2016 on Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2016. I ran the Configuration wizard to create a Single Server Farm but the wizard failed to create the configuration database. Then I tried the PowerShell where I got the same error:

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase –DatabaseName SharePoint_Config –DatabaseServer yyyyyyy –AdministrationContentDatabaseName SharePoint_Content –Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString xxxxxx –AsPlaintext –Force) –FarmCredentials (Get-Credential) -localserverrole SingleServerFarm
```

[image]

I tried [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139515/the-language-is-not-supported-on-the-server) but it seems that the registry key is correct:

[image]

I don't know how to troubleshoot this program, any help will be appreciated!

Many thanks!

For more details, see the log below:

> 12/12/2017 13:42:40  9  ERR                              An exception
>   of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was thrown.  Additional
>   exception information: **The language is not supported on the server.**
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The language is not supported on the
>   server. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The language
>   is not supported on the server.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateSite(Guid
>   gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid
>   gDatabaseId, Guid gSiteSubscriptionId, String bstrDatabaseServer,
>   String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String
>   bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32
>   nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String
>   bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean
>   bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionMajor, Int32 iSprocsVersionMinor, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionBuild, Int32 iSprocsVersionRevision, String
>   bstrSiteSchemaVersion, Boolean bCreateFromMaster, String
>   bstrDenyPermMaskGroupId)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateSite(Guid gApplicationId,
>   String bstrUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, Guid
>   gSiteSubscriptionId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String
>   bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String
>   bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32
>   nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String
>   bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean
>   bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionMajor, Int32 iSprocsVersionMinor, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionBuild, Int32 iSprocsVersionRevision, String
>   bstrSiteSchemaVersion, Boolean bCreateFromMaster, String
>   bstrDenyPermMaskGroupId)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException
>   comEx)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateSite(Guid
>   gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid
>   gDatabaseId, Guid gSiteSubscriptionId, String bstrDatabaseServer,
>   String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String
>   bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32
>   nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String
>   bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String
>   bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean
>   bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32
>   iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionMajor, Int32 iSprocsVersionMinor, Int32
>   iSprocsVersionBuild, Int32 iSprocsVersionRevision, String
>   bstrSiteSchemaVersion, Boolean bCreateFromMaster, String
>   bstrDenyPermMaskGroupId)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.AddInternal(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters
>   param)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteCollectionAddParameters
>   param)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.CreateDefaultInstance(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   administrationContentDatabase, SPWebService adminService, IdentityType
>   identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFactory.CreateAdministrationWebService(SPFarm
>   farm, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase,
>   IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFactory.CreateBasicServices(SPFarm
>   farm)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFactory.Create()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   administrationContentDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   siteMapDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser,
>   SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: Did u install any language pack?

Comment: Yes, Spanish and French

Comment: I am seeing only 2 entries for lp in your registry....so u should have one for English, 1 for French and 1 for Spanish...or you can try to uninstall both then configure SharePoint....once it completed you can install lp again

Answer (score 0):

The error log means you have installed the language pack on this server , but for some reason , the server derecognize .So you need to add another key in your registry .

1033 is valid for US English;

1036 is valid for French ;

For Spanish , please refer to the following web site to determine the value .

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824907.aspx

Then run the Configuration Wizard again .